# How can i move from one activity to another?

Tags: android

I have a question how can i move from one activity to another when i click on text

like"Sgin[in login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLcH8.png)" to move to registration form

Comment: Just add a click listener on your textview and use startActivity to move from one activity to another

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start a new intent, a basic example for that is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NameOfPage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The last activity won't be closed though, you will have to call `finish()` in order to close it afterwards.